# create and present ViewController with lldb, when switching between Swift and Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift, debugging, lldb

How do I present a Swift ViewController programmatically with **lldb**?  The below commands work but the VC I want to show is stuck in the **appearing** state and never gets to the **appeared** state?

[image]

**Step 0**

Write the Swift ViewController...

```
class ydHiddenVC: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        print("code executing in viewDidLoad")
    }
}
```

**Step 1**

Put a breakpoint on the AppDelegate start, where lldb is set to a Swift context...

```
(lldb) exp let $a = ydHiddenVC()
(lldb) po $a
<DELETE_PROV_PROFILE_MACHINE.ydHiddenVC: 0x7fa9f5d00ef0>
(lldb) continue
```

**Step 2**

lldb automagically moves to an Obj-C context after the app loads.

```
(lldb) e id $b = (id)0x7fa9f5d00ef0  // cast the Swift VC to something Objective-C can deal with
(lldb) po [[UIWindow keyWindow] rootViewController]
<UINavigationController: 0x7fa9f783e800>
(lldb) e id $rootvc = (id)0x7fa9f783e800
(lldb) po $rootvc
<UINavigationController: 0x7fa9f783e800>
(lldb) expression (void)[$rootvc pushViewController:$b animated:YES]
(lldb) caflush
code executing in viewDidLoad
```

**Summary**

That looked like success, as my ViewDidLoad code executed.  However, the ViewController did not appear nicely.  It was stuck halfway across the screen, during the transition. With [Chisel](https://github.com/facebook/chisel)'s `pvc` command, you can print what is in the View Hierarchy.  That showed my issue:

```
(lldb) pvc
    <UINavigationController 0x7fa9f783e800>, state: appeared, view: <UILayoutContainerView 0x7fa9f5d10d10>
       | <DELETE_PROV_PROFILE_MACHINE.ydHomeVC 0x7fa9f5f0bc10>, state: disappearing, view: <UIView 0x7fa9f5d0e300>
       | <DELETE_PROV_PROFILE_MACHINE.ydHiddenVC 0x7fa9f5d00ef0>, state: appearing, view: <UIView 0x7fa9f5d14e10>
```

Comment: $b is a swift variable.  There's a bunch of magic involved in making the bridge from swift objects to ObjC, and the objc compiler on its own doesn't know how to do that work.  So the expression evaluator in objc mode can't directly handle swift objects.  But if you get the address of $b (`expr $b` will show you this, for instance) then you should be able to use that - cast as "id" - in an ObjC expression.  Did you try that?

Comment: almost there @JimIngham.  I can get it to load now - as you advised - by casting as (id) - to use the Swift VC inside a Objective-C command..